# Split Java String into Two String using delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string that has the value of `name:score`. I want to split the string into two strings, string `a` with the value of `name` and string `b` with the value of `score`.

What is the correct function/syntax to do this?

I have looked at `string.split`, but can not find the actual syntax to  return the data into two separate strings.

Comment: Did you look at the return value from split()?

Comment: Nevermind, I am an idiot. The values were there the whole time in variable[0] and variable[1].

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `split` function is suitable for that :

```
String[] str_array = "name:score".split(":");
String stringa = str_array[0]; 
String stringb = str_array[1];
```

Comment: what if you have something like this a:1:2 name = a:1?!?@

Comment: It will return an array of strings and will be able to retrieve the 1st and 2nd value

Comment: This code only works if your score does not contain a colon. Be sure to account for this in your code.

Answer (score 6):

You need to look into Regular Expressions:

```
String[] s = myString.split("\\:"); // escape the colon just in case as it has special meaning in a regex
```

Or you can also use a StringTokenizer.

Comment: `:` doesn't have any special meaning on its own

Comment: Never hurts to be safe and escape it... /a{1:2}/ is a case when colon has a special meaning...

Comment: @TraderJoeChicago: No, it doesn't. You're probably talking about `a{1,2}` which matches `a` 1 or 2 times. A colon doesn't have any special meaning on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String [] stringParts = myString.split(":");
```

Comment: But isn't that just creating a new array without moving the data into the other strings?

Comment: @CryptoJones Yes, it is creating a new array of Strings with 2 strings, name and score, which is what you want.

Comment: @CryptoJones - My guess is that `split` returns substrings of the original string and does not actually move any character data. But you shouldn't care. String objects are immutable in Java, and their internal data are inaccessible to your code, so it can't make any difference in what you do later.

Answer (score 2):

```
String row = "name:12345";
String[] columns = row.split(":");
assert columns.length == 2;
String name = columns[0];
int score = Integer.parseInt(columns[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split creates an array with your strings in it:

```
String input = "name:score";
final String[] splitStringArray = input.split(":");
String a = splitStringArray[0];
String b = splitStringArray[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

$ cat Split.java

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        String s = "a:b";
        String res[] = s.split(":");
        System.out.println(res.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
            System.out.println(res[i]);
    }
}
```

$ java Split

```
2
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

what if you have something like this a:1:2 name = a:1??

```
 private String extractName(String str) {
    String[] split = str.split(":");
    return str.replace(split[split.length - 1], "");
  }

  private int extractId(String str){
    String[] split  = str.split(":");
    return  Integer.parseInt(CharMatcher.DIGIT.retainFrom(split[split.length-1]));
  }
```