# splitting string in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

How can I split following string in two strings?

input:

```
00:02:05,130 --> 00:02:10,130
```

output:

```
00:02:05,130
00:02:10,130
```

i tried this piece of code:

```
String[] tokens = my.split(" --> ");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);
    for(String s : tokens)
        System.out.println(s);
```

but the out put is just the first part, what is wrong?

Comment: and also length is 1, but it must be 2

Comment: this may be because the `-->` may not have space around it..try `\\s*-->\\s*`..also check out your input

Comment: i tried that too, but this one has the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use the String `split()`:

```
String str = "00:02:05,130 --> 00:02:10,130";
String[] str_array = str.split(" --> ");
String stringa = str_array[0]; 
String stringb = str_array[1];
```

You may want to have a look at the following: [Split Java String into Two String using delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787385/split-java-string-into-two-string-using-delimiter)

Comment: this one works fine but i want to know what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\s*-->\\s*");
```

Comment: this one has the same problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce. the line `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("00:02:05,130 --> 00:02:10,130".split("\\s*-->\\s*")));` print the splitted array. two elements.