# Count Simultaneous occurs word in String

Tags: java, string

I have a String which contain the duplicate word,i need to calculate the only duplicate word in the string which are occures simultaneously.

```
String a="am abc am am am xyz as xyz xyz xyz xyz";
```

above string i need to count `am` which occures simultaneously i.e. **am occures 3 time** and **xyz occures 4 time** and in this i need to display only **xyz=4** which is maximum **simultaneously** repeated. can any one help me please.

Comment: Ok now, what have you tried?

Comment: "simultaneously" is probably wrong word (I see you are not native English speaker, which is fine). Perhaps you mean "consecutively"? Also, SO question like this really needs to show what you have tried and what is the exact problem you have. SO is not "code this for me" or "give me general hints on how to do this" site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. Create a HashMap of Strings and Integer.
2. Split the given String with the delimiter and create an array of Strings[].
3. Loop through the array of Strings[] and check if the String exists in HashMap,
3.1 if yes, increment the value by 1.
```

**KeyWords** here:

1. [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
2. [Split the Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787385/split-java-string-into-two-string-using-delimiter)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think it will count all duplicate,i need only simultaneously occured duplicate word count.

Comment: I just intended to give you a direction. You will have to implement the logic. :) Try implementing the logic, and if you get stuck you can rephrase the question.