# How to read from a string and split certain words?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a text which I need to read word by word till ';' delimiter...
I have searched in many places and also i have read some chapters but I can't find any method to use... Please help!

string to read i.e 32; Potatoe; Vegetables; 21.30; 12.20; 15 21 32 45;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Java String into Two String using delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787385/split-java-string-into-two-string-using-delimiter)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: there is an exact duplicate of what you have asked here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "32; Potatoe; Vegetables; 21.30; 12.20; 15 21 32 45;";
String[] splittedWords;

splittedWords = s.split(";");
```

You can use the method split to seperate words along delimiters. It will return a list of Strings.
If you want to parse the values in the string to an Integer you can use this:

```
for (String string : splittedWords)
    {
        if(string.matches("[^a-z \\.]+")==true)
        {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(string);

            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

the only integer in your samplestring is 32, though. Thats why this code will only output "32".

Comment: I did that but I cannot parse from String to Int, I get an error while trying to convert with an enhanced for loop

Comment: thnx for answer again.. i tried several things included what u did above but nothing produced the desired output.For explanation: 32 is the article number while others are name, category, price and also quantities. I wanted to add quantities but i couldn't.. thnx again :)

Comment: No Problem... It certainly is possible to parse the other values as well, but that would require a little more sophisticated algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ( String s : myOwnString.split(";") ){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java supports this very clearly, with the `String.split()` method. You can read the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

**Example**

```
String[] tokens = input.split(";");

// tokens contains each value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method of `String`.

```
String string = "32; Potatoe; Vegetables; 21.30; 12.20; 15 21 32 45";
String[] split = string.split(";");

for(String s: split)
{
     System.out.println(s);
}
```

This will print:

```
32
Potatoe
Vegetables
21.30
12.20
15 21 32 45
```

Comment: Thnx I did this but I cant parse to an int for example:  id = Integer.parseInt(s); I get an error

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "32; Potatoe; Vegetables; 21.30; 12.20; 15 21 32 45";
String[] words = new String[text.length()];
int initialIndex = 0,i=0;

while (initialIndex<text.length()) {
    words[i] = text.substring(initialIndex, text.indexOf(";"));
    i++;
    initialIndex = text.indexOf(";")+1;
    }
```

Now String of words contains all words in text.
You can access by 
    word.get(index);