# How to split a string into two parts on specific delimeter

Tags: java, string

I have a string "Rush to ER/F07^e80c801e-ee37-4af8-9f12-af2d0e58e341". 
I want to split it into 2 strings on the delimiter ^. For example string str1=Rush to ER/F07 and String str2 = e80c801e-ee37-4af8-9f12-af2d0e58e341

For getting this i am doing splitting of the string , I followed the tutorial on stackoverflow but it is not working for me , here is a code

```
 String[] str_array = message.split("^");
                    String stringa = str_array[0]; 
                    String stringb = str_array[1];
```

when I am printing these 2 strings I am getting nothing in stringa and in stringb I am getting all the string as it was before the delimiter.

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Java String into Two String using delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787385/split-java-string-into-two-string-using-delimiter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape special regex sign via `\\` try this:

`String[] str_array = message.split("\\^");`

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `.split()` method requires a regex pattern. Escape the ^:

```
String[] str_array = message.split("\\^");
```

You can get more information on this at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-.