# Split a string using a string as delimiter

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to split a string using a string as delimiter? If yes, how?

Example :

```
String myString = "hello_world<;>goodbye<;>foo";
myString.split("<;>");

//returns "hello_world", "goodbye" and "foo"
```

Comment: so your problem is...?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I thought it wasn't possible because I come from the .Net universe and it's not possible that way in it...

Comment: If I could delete this question, I'd do it. But I can't because there are answers... ^^

Comment: For future reference, the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) and Google are both very helpful for questions like this. The exact text of your question summary had the answer as its first result.

Comment: @yshavit Can I have a proof ? Because I've searched and didn't find it. So I thought it was impossible, so I asked this question.

Comment: @Drarig29 http://imgur.com/FGFifvO, though I guess YMMV :) Who knows what those Google elves are up to with personalized results... (I'm not the one who downvoted you, btw, since you expressed contrition in your previous comment :) )

Comment: @yshavit My question was : can I split a string using a string as delimiter ? And your proof is not the answer to my question because in your example they don't use a string as delimiter. But i'm stupid because I didn't try.

Comment: @Drarig29 One of us is confused. :) The [question I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787385/split-java-string-into-two-string-using-delimiter) asked how to split a string using another string as a delimiter. Specifically, they asked how to split "name:score" using the string ":", which is a String of length 1.

Comment: @yshavit Oh sorry ! In .Net the delimiter is of char type... Anyway, good afternoon ;D Could you rebalance the votes by upvoting the question ? ^^

Comment: @Drarig29 heh sorry, I think things are good where they are. :) You lost two points on someone's downvote, and you gained two votes for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in your question works exactly, however this may be coincidental. Keep in mind that the `String.split(...)` method accepts a RegEx parameter, not a String delimiter.

Check out the RegEx documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 1):

yes, exactly as you have in your code.